# MVC3 EditorFor readOnly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, readonly, editorfor

I want to make readOnly with EditorFor in edit page.

I tried to put readonly and disabled as:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userName, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
    </div>
```

However, it does not work. How can I make to disable edit this field?

Thank you.

Comment: If it's a read-only, then it's no longer an editor. It should probably by DisplayFor

Comment: Making an editor readonly kind of defeats the object of it. Why not just use DisplayFor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i set disabled attribute on html textbox in asp.net-mvc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443460/how-do-i-set-disabled-attribute-on-html-textbox-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: The reason one may wish to do user EditorFor (but disabled) is appearance, That is my reason.  DisplayFor creates a text output without enclosing box and has to be CSS adjusted to line up on the form correctly (not difficult, just some padding-top).  But you may want to have a form with all fields in boxes, with ReadOnly values say grayed out.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The EditorFor html helper does not have overloads that take HTML attributes. In this case, you need to use something more specific like TextBoxFor:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.userName, new 
        { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
</div>
```

You can still use EditorFor, but you will need to have a TextBoxFor in a custom EditorTemplate:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [UIHint("userName")]
    public string userName { ;get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder, create a file userName.cshtml. In that file, put this:

```
@model string
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Comment: I can't find the overloads that allow to specify arguments. Is there another extension method I've missed? Can't find it with Intellisense, neither find it in the msdn docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834942(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @JotaBe I think you are right, but I thought I saw these before. Perhaps it was in MVC4 pre-releases, or perhaps I imagined it. Either way, I have updated the answer.

Comment: In the newer versions of MVC (I believe 4+ ?) the `additionalViewData` object can have `htmlAttributes` property which `EditorFor` and the like use for html attributes. So it will become: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.userName, new { htmlAttributes = new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" } })`.

Answer (score 35):

This code is supported in MVC4 onwards

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.userName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" } })
```

Comment: The key change is to wrap the html attributes in the "new { htmlAttributes ="  <your desired attributes> "}" strings.  This appears to be unique pattern for the EditorFor (different that DisplayFor, DropdownFor, etc.)

Comment: I agree with Matthew Lock

Comment: Thing worth mentioning is that ```disabled``` elements won't be passed into the Controller. If you'd like to pass it, use ```readonly```

Answer (score 13):

For those who wonder why you want to use an EditoFor if you don`t want it to be editable, I have an example.

I have this in my Model.

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0: dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime issueDate { get; set; }
```

and when you want to display that format, the only way it works is with an EditorFor, but I have a jquery datepicker for that "input" so it has to be readonly to avoid the users of writting down wrong dates.

To make it work the way I want I put this in the View...

```
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.issueDate, new{ @class="inp", @style="width:200px", @MaxLength = "200"})
```

and this in my ready function...

```
     $('#issueDate').prop('readOnly', true);
```

I hope this would be helpful for someone out there. 
Sorry for my English

Comment: Thank you Seichi! This is the real solution to the exact problem!

Comment: This is a great answer. It describes what the original question is valid, as well as actually answering the OP. Great job!

Comment: Simple straight forward answer thank you very much!   Requirements had me jumping back and forth while reviewing a defect I realized my change to  editorfor allowed my desired DisplayFormating but I discovered  they were no longer read only this was a great find  !!!

Answer (score 6):

You can do it this way:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.userName, new { htmlAttributes = new { disabled = true } })
```

Comment: I finally found a solution in MVC 4, Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

I know the question states MVC 3, but it was 2012, so just in case:

As of MVC 5.1 you can now pass HTML attributes to `EditorFor` like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "", disabled = "" } })
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.userName) <br/>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.userName)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do it:

**Model:**

```
[ReadOnly(true)]
public string Email { get { return DbUser.Email; } }
```

**View:**

```
@Html.TheEditorFor(x => x.Email)
```

**Extension:**

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class CustomExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString TheEditorFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            return iEREditorForInternal(htmlHelper, expression, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
        }

        private static MvcHtmlString iEREditorForInternal<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            if (htmlAttributes == null) htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("div");
            builder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);

            var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);


            string labelHtml = labelHtml = Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor(htmlHelper, expression).ToHtmlString();

            if (metadata.IsRequired)
                labelHtml = Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor(htmlHelper, expression, new { @class = "required" }).ToHtmlString();


            string editorHtml = Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor(htmlHelper, expression).ToHtmlString();

            if (metadata.IsReadOnly)
                editorHtml = Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(htmlHelper, expression).ToHtmlString();


            string validationHtml = Html.ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageFor(htmlHelper, expression).ToHtmlString();

            builder.InnerHtml = labelHtml + editorHtml + validationHtml;

            return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }
    }
}
```

Of course my editor is doing a bunch more stuff, like adding a label, adding a required class to that label as necessary, adding a `DisplayFor` if the property is `ReadOnly` `EditorFor` if its not, adding a `ValidateMessageFor` and finally wrapping all of that in a `Div` that can have `Html Attributes` assigned to it... my `Views` are super clean.

Answer (score 1):

Create an EditorTemplate for a specific set of Views (bound by one Controller):
[image]

In this example I have a template for a Date, but you can change it to whatever you want.

Here is the code in the Data.cshtml:

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>

@Html.TextBox("", @Model != null ? String.Format("{0:d}",     ((System.DateTime)Model).ToShortDateString()) : "", new { @class = "datefield", type =    "date", disabled = "disabled"  @readonly = "readonly" })
```

and in the model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? BlahDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Old post I know.. but now you can do this to keep alignment and all looking consistent..

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.myField, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the `readonly` attribute instead of `disabled` attribute - as this will still submit the value when the field is readonly.

**Note**: Any presence of the readonly attribute will make the field `readonly` even if set to false, so hence why I branch the editor for code like below.

```
 @if (disabled)
 {
     @Html.EditorFor(model => contact.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "" } })
 }
 else
 {
     @Html.EditorFor(model => contact.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting Litisqe Kumar - i'd forgotten how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userName)
</div>
```

Use jquery to disable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#userName').attr('disabled', true);
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

i think this is simple than other by using [Editable(false)] attribute

for example:

```
 public class MyModel
    {
        [Editable(false)]
        public string userName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: adding [Editable(false)] doesn't seem to do anything to make the control readonly

Comment: you should also extend InputTagHelper as I explained in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44639822/6339469