# how to change editor for to read only

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

On the edit screen I am allowing the user to edit a record.
But I dont want them to edit the lastUseDate. How can I set it to read only, instead of EditorFor LastUseDate, disabled?

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Device.LastUseDate)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC3 EditorFor readOnly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109185/mvc3-editorfor-readonly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Device.LastUseDate, new { @readonly = "readonly", disabled = "disabled", }) %>
```

Comment: I fix it, now you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Device.LastUseDate, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

It'll add disabled and readonly attribute to your textbox.