# Change password box to disabled

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How can I change the password box to disabled.

```
@Html.Editor("password")
```

something like

```
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.User, new {disabled = "disabled"})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC3 EditorFor readOnly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109185/mvc3-editorfor-readonly)

Comment: @wizkid- not since I try it and its not working for password

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You have to prefix your attributes with `@`:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.User, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read only text box using Html Attributes

> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.User, new { @readonly="readonly",
>   style = "width:80%;" })