# ASP ViewModel from controller (the Model not model => model.FieldName) became null when postback to controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, null

I have an mvc aspx page with strongly typed model, it looked like this

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<DeliveryService.ViewModels.DeliveryRequestViewModel>" %>
```

so when I call a create function, the page shows the initialized data from the view model

but when I submit the form (calling the postback create function)

I got a null exception error like on the line:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FromGroup, Model.LocationList) %>
```

the error pointed to Model.LocationList

I have another field in the aspx page, but it doesn't triggering null exception, the code looks like this

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address) %>
```

Please point my error, why is when I use the Model with capital at the first letter I get a null exception error. Thank you very much

I have an extra question:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeliveryRequestNumber, new {@readonly = "readonly"}) %>
```

what is the correct syntax to create a readonly textbox using editorfor? tried this but, the rendered html code is

```
<input class="text-box single-line valid" id="DeliveryRequestNumber" name="DeliveryRequestNumber" type="text" value="somevaluegeneratedfrommodel">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1 Why do I get a NRE?**

I'm guessing, but your reference to 'PostBack' might mean that you come from a WebForms background. In MVC, controller actions must always return the FULL state required to render the view (e.g. in the ViewModel), even after a POST:

```
[HttpPost]
ActionResult Create(DeliveryRequestViewModel someModel)
{
   //  Do something
   return View("SomeView", someModel); <-- Remember to pass the ViewModel again
}
```

**2 Re : Model vs model**

> Please point my error, why is when I use the Model with capital at the first letter I get a null exception error. Thank you very much

`Model` is an instance of the type of the page's model - `DeliveryRequestViewModel` in this case. (From `Inherits="ViewPage<DeliveryRequestViewModel>` of the .aspx, or from `@model` in razor)

Whereas in this case:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address) %>
```

`model` is a placeholder variable for a lambda expression which projects the `Address` property off the variable. Placeholder, because it could be anything, e.g.

```
Html.EditorFor(foo => foo.Address)
```

**3 Re:Readonly Text Box**

[This here has some ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10111598/314291)

Also, I guess you could just use `Html.DisplayFor` if you just want to render the value?

Comment: worked perfectly! thank you so much mr Stuart :D
also thanks for the Model and model explanation, and for the readonly problems too